# Get user banner in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Is there any way to obtain user banner on discord using discord.js? User banner is new feature, so I am not sure if there is any way so far. I didn't find anything in docs. Eg. server banner is available on:

`https://cdn.discordapp.com/banners/GUILD_ID/GUILD_BANNER.png`.

Something similar for user banner would be great.

Comment: There is nothing in [the official documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user) about getting a users banner, so as of now I do not believe there is a way. However this feature is still in discord BETA so keep an eye out as they may release an endpoint soon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to recover a discord banner after several hours of development, the code below :

( you need to install "node-fetch" => npm i node-fetch )

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

let uid = "user_id"

let response = fetch(`https://discord.com/api/v8/users/${uid}`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bot ${client.token}`
    }
})

let receive = ''
let banner = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/829722741288337428/834016013678673950/banner_invisible.gif' // invisible image ( you can change the link if you want )

response.then(a => {
if(a.status !== 404) {
a.json().then(data => {
receive = data['banner']

if(receive !== null) {

let format = 'png'
if(receive.substring(0,2) === 'a_') {
format = 'gif'
}

banner = `https://cdn.discordapp.com/banners/${uid}/${receive}.${format}`

}})

.setTimeout(() => {

// To retrieve the value "banner" we put a timeout otherwise it will return us the first definition of "banner" that is to say the invisible image, I let you modify the code as you wish, good evening to you (and also I just wanted to make it clear I'm French)

// Put the rest of your code here :

}, 1000)
```

Comment: You're welcome ^^, have a good day Michal and I wish you good development ! :D

Answer (score 4):

### Simple solution

The simplest solution for discord.js v12 I came up with:

```js
async function getUserBannerUrl(userId) {
    const user = await client.api.users(userId).get();
    return user.banner ? `https://cdn.discordapp.com/banners/${userId}/${user.banner}?size=512` : null;
}
```

However this doesn't handle mime types well. You don't know what the mime type is unless you read the `content-type` header. This may break some things that require you to have a file extension in your URL. That's why I came up with more complex solution.

### Complex solution

The code below is dependent on [`axios`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios).

```js
const axios = require("axios");
```

```js
async function getUserBannerUrl(userId, { dynamicFormat = true, defaultFormat = "webp", size = 512 } = {}) {

    // Supported image sizes, inspired by 'https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ImageURLOptions'.
    if (![16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096].includes(size)) {
        throw new Error(`The size '${size}' is not supported!`);
    }

    // We don't support gif as a default format,
    // because requesting .gif format when the original image is not a gif,
    // would result in an error 415 Unsupported Media Type.
    // If you want gif support, enable dynamicFormat, .gif will be used when is it available.
    if (!["webp", "png", "jpg", "jpeg"].includes(defaultFormat)) {
        throw new Error(`The format '${defaultFormat}' is not supported as a default format!`);
    }

    // We use raw API request to get the User object from Discord API,
    // since the discord.js v12's one doens't support .banner property.
    const user = await client.api.users(userId).get();
    if (!user.banner) return null;

    const query = `?size=${size}`;
    const baseUrl = `https://cdn.discordapp.com/banners/${userId}/${user.banner}`;

    // If dynamic format is enabled we perform a HTTP HEAD request,
    // so we can use the content-type header to determine,
    // if the image is a gif or not.
    if (dynamicFormat) {
        const { headers } = await axios.head(baseUrl);
        if (headers && headers.hasOwnProperty("content-type")) {
            return baseUrl + (headers["content-type"] == "image/gif" ? ".gif" : `.${defaultFormat}`) + query;
        }
    }

    return baseUrl + `.${defaultFormat}` + query;

}
```

### Example usage

Implementing simple `!banner` command, that will show the message sender's banner.

```js
client.on("message", async (message) => {

    if (message.author.bot) return;

    if (message.content == "!banner") {
        const bannerUrl = await getUserBannerUrl(message.author.id, { size: 4096 });
        if (bannerUrl) {
            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(`${message.author.username}'s banner`)
                .setDescription("Look at my banner, how cool is that?")
                .setImage(bannerUrl);
            message.channel.send(embed);
        } else {
            message.channel.send("You don't have money to buy Discord Nitro... How sad...");
        }
    }

});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to a response to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/3095#issuecomment-868817186) and [the official documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user), there is no current way to read the user bio and banner.

As Tyler stated, the feature is still in beta. Once added, you should be able to *serialize the banner image hash on the user object*, thus allowing bots to receive the field passively.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the discord user banner with [discord-banner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-banner) npm package

Its so easy to use it and allow you to get it for now without Discord.js v13