# discord.js displaying pinged user banner

Tags: discord.js

i wanna make it display the pinged user banner
heres my code. it only shows the user thats using the command banner.

````
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'banner',
    category: "utility",
    description: "Get a user's/your banner",
    run: async(client, message, args) => {
        if (!args[0]) {

        async function getUserBannerUrl(userId) {
            const user = await client.api.users(userId).get();
            return user.banner ? `https://cdn.discordapp.com/banners/${userId}/${user.banner}?size=512` : null;
        }
        const bannerUrl = await getUserBannerUrl(message.author.id, { size: 4096 });
        if (bannerUrl) {
            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(`${users.username}'s banner`)
                .setColor('#2f3136')
                .setImage(bannerUrl);
            message.channel.send(embed);
        } else {
            message.channel.send("buy discord boost you peasant");
        }
    }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get user banner in discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68334431/get-user-banner-in-discord-js)

Comment: Either of these particular solutions from that duplicate question should work: [simple way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68582398/6901876) or [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68447835/6901876).

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way of getting the user's banner "easy way" from the module, but I just looked around the StackOverflow and found similar question with seemingly working solution, you should check it out.

[Get user banner in discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68334431/get-user-banner-in-discord-js)